# Thumbnail path isn't saved in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have simple code for image upload which also create thumbnail of image while is uploading. The problem is that the thumbnail is saved into directory but in database isn't saved the path to the thumbnail. The path to the original image is saved properly.

This is the code

```
    $image = $request->file('image');

    if( $image && $image->isValid()){

        $imagename = str_random(20).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension(); 

        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads');
        $thumb_img = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200);
        $thumb_img->save($destinationPath.'/thub_'.$imagename,80);

        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $imagename);                            
    }

    $item->image = $imagename;
    $item->image_thumb = $thumb_img;
```

So, `$item->image_thumb = $thumb_img;` isn't getting saved in database. I have added column `image_thumb` in `fillable` in my model also.

What can be the problem?

Comment: You need to get `$thumb_img` name first, then you save it to your DB column! Like: `$thumb_img = $destinationPath.'/thub_'.$imagename;`

Comment: Don't forgot to accept best answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $thumb_img = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200);
 $thumb_img->save($destinationPath.'/thub_'.$imagename,80);
 $thumb_img = $destinationPath.'/thub_'.$imagename;
```